# Making line plot with discrete x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-plot

I am building a ggplot2 figure with a facet grid. On my Y-axis are percentages, and my X-axis is the concentration (in numbers). Each facet has 3 groups (0, 24 and 48 hours)

```
ggplot(data=MasterTable, aes(x=Concentration, y=Percentage, group=Time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(Chemicals ~ Treatments)
```

This generates a continuous x-axis. Since the values are not evenly spread out, I would prefer a discrete axis to better visualize my data. I followed the [following tutorial](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) with no luck. The first figure is exactly what I am trying to do.

I also tried formatting the axis:

```
scale_x_discrete(labels("0", "0.1", "2", "50"))
```

and formatting the line:

```
geom_line(aes(Time))
```

and following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564607/how-to-change-x-axis-tick-label-names-order-and-boxplot-colour-using-r-ggplot).

I think this problem is that the values on the x-axis are integers rather than strings. This makes the default axis continuous. How can I change this?? I am sure the solution is simple, I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! I did convert my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this [page](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-line-plot-quick-start-guide-r-software-and-data-visualization) they make the following modification `df2$dose<-as.factor(df2$dose)`. You can try to modify your `x-axis` as `df2$Concentration<-as.factor(df2$Concentration)`

or like this:

```
ggplot(data=MasterTable, aes(x=factor(Concentration), y=Percentage, group=Time)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(Chemicals ~ Treatments)
```

Comment: Thank you! Spent hours on this one. Was so simple! `MasterTable$Concentration <- as.factor(MasterTable$Concentration)`