# change labeling x axis boxplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am quite new in ggplot and I have a question to relabelling the x-axis when I use boxplots.

```
  mat <- as.data.frame(cbind(sample(1:120,5000, replace = TRUE), rnorm(500)))
  colnames(mat) <- c("category","value")
  mat$category <- as.factor(mat$category)

  library(ggplot2)

  p <- ggplot(mat, aes(x=category, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
    xlab("Category") + 
    ylab("Value in units")
  p
```

The problem is the x-axis as the numbers are difficult to read.
My idea is to use a kind of sequence to have fewer numbers or in boxplot case fewer categories written on the x-axis.

My question is where to include something like the following sequence

```
new_x_labeling = c(1,seq(10,120,5))
```

I found just answer about changing names in

[How to change x-axis tick label names, order and boxplot colour using R ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564607/how-to-change-x-axis-tick-label-names-order-and-boxplot-colour-using-r-ggplot)

but I have no clue how to reduce the number of names.

https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3364_d1a578f521174152b46b19d0c83cbe7e.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that probably:

```
  ggplot(mat, aes(x=category, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot() + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(1, seq(10, 120, 5))) +
    theme_classic() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
    labs(x = "Category", y = "Value in units")
```

[image]

Comment: Never thought that was thateasy. I have tried   
    scale_x_discrete( c(1, seq(10, 120, 5))) and nothing happened.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the `ggplot2` grammar is not so intuitive, as I'd wish it to be.